# FFmpeg : how to burn any kinds of subtitle into videos

Tags: batch-file, video, command-line, ffmpeg, video-processing

as title, i want to encode hardsub some mkv videos which contain subtitles. These subs is maybe ASS, SRT or picture-based.
I have read FFmpeg Document and stuffs, but only found the way to burn sub if the type of sub is known.

I try to get subtitle info using mediainfo:

```
mediainfo "--Output=Text;%Format%\r\n" input.mkv
```

The output is "ASS" with ass , "Text" or "Subrip" or "UTF-8" with SRT....
But i find it hard to keep going because of many kind of output i can get, which is still so hard to create a batch file to tell ffmpeg to auto dectected kind of subs so auto choose correct filter.

Is there any ways to do this? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `ffmpeg`, so here's my guess.

```
for /f %%G in ('mediainfo "--Output=Text;%Format%\r\n" input.mkv') do (
    set type=%%G
)

rem rename Text, Subrip and UTF-8 to SRT
if "%type%"=="Text"   set type=SRT
if "%type%"=="Subrip" set type=SRT
if "%type%"=="UTF-8"  set type=SRT

rem ffmpeg burn as %type%
```

Explanation:

- Gets result of `mediainfo` and set it into variable `type`
- If `type` is equal to "Text"/"Subrip"/"UTF-8", set it to "SRT"
- Burn the file(I don't know the command)

Note: if you want to loop through a list of files, you will need a double loop like so:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%A in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f %%G in ('mediainfo "--Output=Text;%Format%\r\n" %%A') do (
        set type=%%G
    )

    if "!type!"=="Text"   set type=SRT
    if "!type!"=="Subrip" set type=SRT
    if "!type!"=="UTF-8"  set type=SRT

    rem ffmpeg burn as %type%
)
```

- Loops through all `.mkv` files and;

  - Gets result of `mediainfo` and set it into variable `type`
  - If `type` is equal to "Text"/"Subrip"/"UTF-8", set it to "SRT"
  - Burn the file(I don't know the command)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I also need your suggestion in order to solve this problem, thanks again.
The main problem is, not only SRT, but also ASS and picture-based sub. So there will be so many cases...
Is there a way to detect as if the sub is picture-based or text-based ?

Comment: In that case, if you know all the possibility, you can `for` and `if`. Otherwise, you may need ffmpeg to simplify the all format into only 3 options.

Comment: @MinhLee Also, if it is possible for ffmpeg to simplify the formats into the three formats, it will be much better. If it can't, then we may manually covert Text to SRT, and so on. A`for + if` statement will greatly help.